# How to find the sum of 2 discrete random variables

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

Let X and Y be independent random discrete variables and 
$X = \begin{pmatrix}-1&0&1\\\frac13&\frac13&\frac13\end{pmatrix}$ and $Y = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\\frac13&\frac23\end{pmatrix}$

Then what is $X + Y$? As a discrete random variable.. I understood that I have to add the first row just like in matrix addition but what happens when they don't have the same size and how to add the probabilities? Also what is the difference between independent variables and incompatible variables?

The missing entries were:

$X + Y = \begin{pmatrix}-1&0&1&2\\\frac19&\frac39&\frac39&\frac29\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: "I understood that I have to add the first row just like in matrix addition": no, like in a convolution.

Comment: Why? In which point?

Comment: @RobertZ Then a lot of them are wrong... Because it doesn't add up to 1

Comment: @RobertZ the one at $0$ should also be $\frac 39$, right? Now it should be okay

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks! Can you help me with my last question too, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I understood that I have to add the first row just like in matrix addition". This is not true even when they have the same size.

Note that $X+Y\in\{-1,0,1,2\}$:

i) $X+Y=-1$ iff $(X,Y)=(-1,0)$, therefore, since $X$ and $Y$ are  independent ,
 $$p(X+Y=-1)=p(\{X=-1\} \cap \{Y=0\})=p(X=-1)\cdot p(Y=0)=\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{9}.$$

ii) $X+Y=0$ iff $(X,Y)\in\{(-1,1),(0,0)\}$;

iii) $X+Y=1$ iff $(X,Y)\in\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$;

iv) $X+Y=2$ iff $(X,Y)=(1,1)$.

Can you take it from here and fill the missing entries?

$$X+Y = \begin{pmatrix}-1&0&1&0\\\frac19&?&?&?\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: So then $X + Y$ must have $4$ values, right? And also if $(X, Y)\in \{(-1, 1), (0,0)\}$, for example, then the probability will be $P(X=-1,Y=1)P(X=0, Y=0)$ for that $X + Y = 0$? Also what would happen if the events were rather incompatible then independent? Also what happens when they are compatible?

Comment: If $X,Y$ are compatible you should have more information in order to compute $p(X=a\cap Y=b)$. You need also the joint distribution. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21549/how-to-add-two-dependent-random-variables

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Can you enumerate all the cases? For example, if $X+Y=1$ it means either $X=0$, $Y=1$ (probability $\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}=\frac{2}{9}$) or $X=1$, $Y=0$ (probability $\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{9}$) $\Longrightarrow P\left(X+Y=1\right)=\frac{2}{9}+\frac{1}{9}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an $x$ and an $y$, you can obtain one of $-1,0,1$ or $0,1,2$, with probabilities equal to the product of respective probabilities. You see that there is an overlap on $0$ and $1$; just cumulate the corresponding probabilities.